# Why do I get different results with two ways of checking whether a number is an Armstrong number or not?

Tags: c

I am writing a very basic program in C to check whether a number is an Armstrong number or not and I am having some trouble in understanding why one version works and the other doesn't.

My code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n,num,rem,sum=0;
    printf("enter n: \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    
    for(num=n;num!=0;num/=10){
        rem=num%10;
        
        sum+=rem*rem*rem;
    
    }
    if(sum==n){
        printf("armstrong number");
    }
    else{
        printf("not");
        }
    return 0;
}
enter n:
153
armstrong number
--------------------------------
Process exited after 2.716 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Now, this runs smoothly, no problem. But when I write

```
if(sum==num)
```

the code shows that 153 (which is an Armstrong number) is not an Armstrong number!
I have already written `num=n;` then why does changing `num` and `n` in the `if` statement show different results?

This is the result when I put `num` in `if` statement.

```
enter n:
153
not an armstrong number
--------------------------------
Process exited after 1.702 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: What do you think `num/=10` in the for header does?

Answer (score 3):

`num` is modified during the `for` loop while `n` isn't.

`num` will be zero after the `for` loop because the loop condition is `num!=0`.

Therefore, `num` after the `for` loop doesn't have information to judge if `n` is an armstrong number.